# Configure Laravel environment just once and use it for further app developments

Tags: laravel, development-environment, environment

I am pretty new to Laravel and just started with development of my first application in the framework. I had started learning it a while ago and faced n number of issues while configuring the test application. It had been a long time and I can't find all the notes I had made while I faced issues.

So my problem is this time I want to configure my environment and create a package or a container so that I get it up and running next time when I want to develop more apps in future. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What specific problems are you having? Laravel's out-of-the-box environment configuration should have you covered. Have you tried looking at a tool like Vagrant? It will allow you to define reproducible virtual machines that you can run your application inside of.

Comment: @Chris White: Thanks for the comment. However, I haven't used Vagrant before, but would like to explore it. It might sound dumb, but is it possible, that I can create a vagrant image of my current local OS and server environment (it's Ubuntu)?

Comment: It's possible, but ideally you would create a new one from a base image (a base image is basically a fresh install of an operating system such as Ubuntu). This will allow you to install only the dependencies that your application needs, and it will keep the machine as small as possible.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Thanks for the info. Where can I get this base image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a clean and complete development environment for laravel and spare yourself of configuring everything on your local OS and *Be able to have the same configuration* somewhere else on another machine, I'd recommend using homestead which you can find it's documentation [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead).

Steps are easy you basically install vagrant and VirtualBox or VMWare. (I recommend VirtualBox). Then install homestead by following the [Per Project Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#per-project-installation) section of the docs and you're gonna have a `Homestead.yaml` file in your laravel installation. Which is going to look something like this :

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: myhost
name: myhost
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Path/To/Project/myapp"
      to: "/home/vagrant/myapp"

sites:
    - map: my.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/myapp/public"

databases:
    - mydatabase
# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar
# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Edit this file to your settings and save it for future use. Then just add `my.app  *Your.Ip.Add.ress*` to your OS hosts file which you're gonna find the guide on how to do that in the docs as well.

Finally run `vagrant up` in your project root and have everything setup!
Just type `my.app` or whatever you set it up to be and your laravel website comes up.

You can ssh to this virtual server installation with `vagrant ssh` command.
Database username is `homestead` and password is `secret` by default. you can change all of this yourself in the virtual server.

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I will use homestead hereafter as it becomes very frustrating to configure the entire dev platform again.